# Class not found exception at org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect

Tags: android, facebook, cordova

I am using the same code at

https://github.com/jimzim/phonegap-facebook-android-sample/blob/master/platforms/android/assets/www/index.html

In Config.xml, i have added below codes

```
      <feature name="org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect"><param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.facebook.ConnectPlugin" />

 </feature>
```

[image]

What i have did wrong?

Please help me

Thanks

Comment: Please anyone help me.I am frustrated still i have not solve my problem.

Comment: Clean the project and try it should work

Comment: @shammon i have tried it but with no success